# libxml2 with C language on XML file

Tags: c, xml, parsing, printf, libxml2

I'm working on XML file (in particula .osm file) with libxml2 and C language.

This is my XML source (not all but just a piece):

```
...
        <way id="9484424" visible="true" version="8" changeset="11179686" timestamp="2012-04-04T18:01:31Z" user="Davlak" uid="217070">
      <nd ref="72843570"/>
      <nd ref="963203594"/>
      <nd ref="612588857"/>
      <nd ref="300164764"/>
      <nd ref="72843572"/>
      <tag k="highway" v="unclassified"/>
      <tag k="name" v="Via Giorgio Pitacco"/> 
      <tag k="odbl" v="clean"/>
      <tag k="oneway" v="yes"/>
     </way>
     <way id="11378242" visible="true" version="29" changeset="22876351" timestamp="2014-06-11T18:00:17Z" user="Davlak" uid="217070">
      <nd ref="101181728"/>
      <nd ref="2911704721"/>
      <nd ref="2911704714"/>
      <nd ref="101181731"/>
      <tag k="foot" v="yes"/>
      <tag k="highway" v="trunk_link"/>
      <tag k="lanes" v="2"/>
      <tag k="lit" v="yes"/>
      <tag k="maxspeed" v="40"/>
      <tag k="mofa" v="no"/>
      <tag k="moped" v="no"/>
      <tag k="motorroad" v="yes"/>
      <tag k="name" v="Circonvallazione Tiburtina"/>
      <tag k="oneway" v="yes"/>
      <tag k="sidewalk" v="right"/>
     </way>
     <way id="20507982" visible="true" version="11" changeset="17228559" timestamp="2013-08-05T14:00:29Z" user="Davlak" uid="217070">
      <nd ref="219557958"/>
      <nd ref="1920238894"/>
      <nd ref="1701671630"/>
      <nd ref="1920238892"/>
      <nd ref="219557991"/>
      <tag k="highway" v="residential"/>
      <tag k="lit" v="yes"/>
      <tag k="name" v="Via Prenestina"/>
     </way>
     <way id="20507983" visible="true" version="14" changeset="26174383" timestamp="2014-10-18T17:12:55Z" user="Privits" uid="2009312">
      <nd ref="219558042"/>
      <nd ref="2276045993"/>
      <nd ref="2023496104"/>
      <nd ref="219558031"/>
      <nd ref="2276045996"/>
      <nd ref="922740441"/>
      <nd ref="922740415"/>
      <nd ref="3137149509"/>
      <nd ref="1620785409"/>
      <nd ref="219558021"/>
      <nd ref="301486927"/>
      <nd ref="298561544"/>
      <tag k="highway" v="residential"/>
      <tag k="lanes" v="1"/>
      <tag k="name" v="Via Prenestina"/>
      <tag k="oneway" v="yes"/>
      </way>

 ...
```

My output, right now , is (so using the following code i'm printing):

```
way: 9484424
 node: 72843570
 node: 963203594
 node: 612588857
 node: 300164764
 node: 72843572
```

and so on for each way element...

I would like to print, for each way, ONLY the first and the last node, in the same line, and the way that these nodes connect. For example:

```
node: 72843570 node: 72843572 way: 9484424
```

This is my code actually:

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <libxml/parser.h>
#include <libxml/tree.h>


int is_leaf(xmlNode * node) {

    xmlNode * child = node->children;

    while(child)  {

        if(child->type == XML_ELEMENT_NODE) return 0;

    child = child->next;
  }

  return 1;
}

void print_xml(xmlNode * node, int indent_len) {
        char *name= "way";
        char *nd = "nd";
    while(node)    {

        if(node->type == XML_ELEMENT_NODE)  {
            if(strcmp (node->name, name) ==0)  {

                printf("%*c%s: %s\n", indent_len*2, ' ', node->name, is_leaf(node)?xmlNodeGetContent(node):xmlGetProp(node, "id"));

            }

        }

        if(node->type == XML_ELEMENT_NODE)  {
            if(strcmp (node->name, nd) ==0)  {

                printf("%*c%s: %s\n", indent_len*2, ' ', "node", is_leaf(node)?xmlNodeGetContent(node):xmlGetProp(node, "ref"));

            }

        }
        print_xml(node->children, indent_len + 1);
        node = node->next;

    }
}

int main() {
  xmlDoc *doc = NULL;
  xmlNode *root_element = NULL;

  doc = xmlReadFile("Casal.osm", NULL, 0);

  if (doc == NULL) {
    printf("Could not parse the XML file");
  }

  root_element = xmlDocGetRootElement(doc);

  print_xml(root_element, 1);

  xmlFreeDoc(doc);

  xmlCleanupParser();
}
```

I'm not able to save or to store the first and last node and print every way during the scan. How can I modify my code? THank you everybody.

Comment: maybe in this way is more detailed and easy to undestand. Thank you

Comment: I will first print the node->type of the tag where you miss to print the properties and once you know that put an else if(node->type == XML_..) in your if(node->type == XML_ELEMENT_NODE) statament.

Comment: In pugixml it would be simply:   `// Find attribute via predicate
doc.last_child().find_attribute(allow_remote_predicate()).value();`

Comment: which is the function that I can use to print the node->type?

Comment: @Claudio You can simply use a printf("Node type is: %d",node->type) because it is a number and you can see the possible value here: http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-tree.html searching for Enum xmlElementType